# C++: Passing array of structs to functions by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Please do not mark as duplicate, while there are similar questions to mine, they were either answered using pointers, did not address the same issue that I have, or they pertained to the language C instead of C++.

I am trying to pass an array of structs to a function, but when I try to do so, I am getting an error: `declaration of ‘a’ as array of references`. I think the problem may lay in the fact the compiler is reading it as an array instead of as a struct, but I am not sure how to remedy this problem.

I have defined a struct of three elements:

```
struct StructA {
   string name; 
   float income; 
   int amount; 
}
```

Declared this struct within main:

```
StructA a[15];
```

And am passing it to a function like so:

```
void FunctionA(StructA& a[], int& count) { //& to pass by reference

}
```

Furthermore, right below the definition of StructA, I have the matching function prototype for the function above.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Someone marked this question as a duplicate of another; it is not. I am in an intro to programming class, and as I clearly stated up top, I cannot use a pointer. Guess what the other question uses? A pointer. See the difference? Furthermore, on a more practical level, I already tried the solution recommended in [Pass a dynamic array of objects to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860967/pass-a-dynamic-array-of-objects-to-function) and it did not work for me and since I cannot comment in the other question, I have to ask a new question. I will just wait until I can ask my professor, grazie.

Comment: Is it a must to have to have an array? If not try declaring a `std::vector<T>` of `StructA` and pass a `std::vector<StructA>& container` to your function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
void FunctionA(StructA (&a) [SIZE], int &count)
```

`SIZE` should be mentioned in this case.

Your syntax (`void FunctionA(StructA &a [SIZE])`) means that you pass array of references(&) not a reference to an array.

You can also use a template with the function:

```
template <size_t Size>
void FunctionA(StructA (&a) [SIZE])
```

You do not need to pass `count` if you mean it to be `size` of the array as noted by:Amadeus

Using template will enable the function for different sizes as answered by: James Root

You can use the function then as follows:

```
StructA a[10];
StructA b[20];

FunctionA(a);
FunctionA(b);
```

Comment: Used your method but I am getting a new error: `parameter ‘a’ includes reference to array of unknown bound`

Comment: @Matt: you should use SIZE. I edit the answer and make it more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array of any size by reference, you can do:

```
template <size_t Size>
void FunctionA(StructA (&a)[Size])
```

It'll deduce the size of the array, so you don't need to specify it each time.

```
StructA a1[10];
StructA a2[15];

FunctionA(a1);
FunctionA(a2);
```